# Stackexchange.com "my logins" do not show icons for OpenID logins or the "Remove" button

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com

When I check my user page on stackexchange.com and then click on *my logins*, it does show all OpenID logins, but without any icon or the *Remove* (X) button.

[image: Screenshot of stackexchange.com]

On any other SE site however, the logins are displayed as well as the *Remove* (X) button. Here's an example from Super User:

[image: Screenshot from Super User]

Is this "by design" or a bug?

EDIT: No difference in Firefox 14.0.1, Chrome 21.0 and Internet Explorer 9.0.

Comment: reproduced in chrome. Doubt it's intentional

Comment: @Ben Brocka: Woops, forgot to mention the browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for now for technical reasons.  Stackexchange.com isn't *really* a part of the network so it doesn't have access to remove credentials directly.  You can edit your credentials on any network site.